# How to implement MAC-DOCK-like selection behavior with vertical sections scrollbar in UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scrollbar, uitableview

Currently, I'm displaying vertical section scrollbar in my table view:

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return [SectionModel getAllSectionNames];
}
```

I need to zoom-in the section name that is tapped on scrollbar, and zoom-in a little bit previous and next section names. The desired effect should be similar to DOCK behavior in MAC OS X. Any suggestions where to start?

UPDATE: Currently, I'm trying to find any scroll-to-section event but with no luck. UIScrollViewDelegate do not have such method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I have realized that it's impossible to do that with native Apple methods. You need to implement that scrollbar from scratch.

Another option would be to use UIScrollViewDelegate method sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex: that gets called when you tap on concrete section on scrollbar.Then you might create custom UIView with zoomed-in letter and present it on tableviews superview (for example at center). It's not the desired effect but some workaround.